# ANOVA 3X3, what are the steps (by hand)

Tags: anova, clinical-trials

For my dissertation project, I have proposed a randomised controlled trial. My independent variable consists of 3 groups: one receiving AVATAR-cognitive therapy, one receiving Cognitive Therapy, and one receiving Treatment as usual. My other independent variable is time, measured at 3 points, pre-test, post-test, and follow-up. Since this is a research proposal, I have no actual data other than this. 
Could you provide me with directions as to how to perform the statistical analysis(the formulas I need and logical order) step by step? (not in SPSS, by hand)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is not possible to answer your question as it stands, but maybe it is possible to make some comments that might assist your investigation.

1. **Design.** You are making two kinds of comparisons and they are structurally different. So your design will not be a simple two-factor ANOVA with three levels of each factor. Let's look at the sub-designs within your grand experiment.

(a) **Across time.** Consider one of your three groups. Each subject will have an exam at three time points: pre, post, and follow-up. When you compare pre vs. post, you should be looking at the difference between pre and post for each subject in the group. If you compared only pre and post, that would amount to a paired test (a paired t test, if your test scores are nearly normal). The generalization of 'pair' is 'block'. So each subject can be considered a block with three scores. Within each group, we have a a block design as a sub-design for the grand experiment with three groups. (If scores are not normal, a Friedman test might be used for the comparing time periods across blocks.)

(b) **Among groups.** Now consider comparisons among groups. To simplify initially, suppose each subject in each group has one score which is the average of pre, post, and follow-up scores. Because different groups involve different subjects, this part of the analysis will consider three independent groups. If there were two groups (with normal scores) it would like a 2-sample t test. The generalization of a 2-sample t test to three groups is a one-factor ANOVA will three levels of the factor. (If scores are not normal, a Kruskal-Wallis test could be used to start
investigating differences among groups.)

(c) **Synthesis.** In analyzing the data, I would probably want to do (a) and (b) first, and if circumstances permit, make a larger design for the whole experiment. If data are normal and variances across groups and times are about the same, then you could make a partially-hierarchical ANOVA design that includes comparisons among methods, comparisons among times, and possible interactions between methods and times. [A priori, it is conceivable be that the AVITAR group could show huge differences across time while the Treatment group shows smaller differences (or none). That would be a group-by-time interaction. If present, it might complicate overall comparisons among groups. So it is worthwhile to design and perform the more complex ANOVA, if possible.]

2. **Computer analysis.** I see no feasible way to do the analysis of your experiment by hand.
   Preliminary bits and pieces, perhaps. But not the whole thing. So the prospectus for your experiment will have to discuss the steps and pieces of the analysis and how they might be done using software.

To some extent, you will have to have a good look at your data before you can know exactly what kinds of tests to perform initially. And then to see whether a grand ANOVA design is feasible, and if not, what can be used as a substitute.

You say you don't want to use SPSS, and I would never argue with anyone wanting to avoid SPSS (or any other specific software). But you will have to learn
how to do the analysis using ***some*** kind of software, or find someone who can do it for you. [I did an analysis roughly similar to the one required here about 30 years ago; fortunately, suitable software had been available for at least 20 years at that time.]

Comment: I should mention a few things. Firstly,  it is a proposal so it`s all preliminary, so I will roughly have to explain the hypothesis, a few of the steps, and how i decide whether my results are significant or not.So I was recommended to do a mixed 2X3 ANOVA for each depedent variable(they are 2). If the results are significant,  My tutor said something about post-hoc tests, so t test between subject at post-test and follow up(so these are 2 t-tests?) and t tests within subject to see how do the effects evolve in time( so 3 tests? 1 testing pre-post , one post-follow up and one pre-follow up?

Comment: Also, he mentioned that when choosing the sample size in gpower I should adjust alpha with a bonferroni correction.  So do i have to divide alpha by 3(since there are 3 pair-wise comparisons?) Also, the p value that I come up after the correction will be the one used in my ANOVA? Sorry if it`s not quite clear, I really new at statistics and this level of analysis beats me

Comment: Thank you so much for your input and effort!!